# How to secure a TURN server for WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, turn, rfc5766turnserver

I've just installed rfc5766-turn-server (https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/) on an Amazon server in order to relay my WebRTC calls.

Since authentication username and password will be distributed to every client in WebRTC `iceServers`, how can I ensure that **only** my clients use my TURN to relay their call?

Comment: if all you've got is a user/pass, how are you planning on detecting if/when a client shares their credentials with someone else?

Comment: That's my question. Does rfc5766-turn-server provide any other authentication mechanism?

Comment: That turn server implementation allows for a [TURN REST API](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/wiki/turnserver#TURN_REST_API) that should help secure your client's access.

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question?

Comment: coturn supports database-based authentication so you can create short-term credentials if you know when your session ended

Comment: despite coturn documentation says database access is for long-term credentials, it reloads the credentials immediately

Answer (score 8):

You can use this instead https://code.google.com/p/coturn/. It's  evolved from rfc5766-turn-server project.

Supported TURN authentication mechanisms:

- 'classic' long-term credentials mechanism;
- TURN REST API (a modification of the long-term mechanism, for time-limited secret-based authentication, for WebRTC applications: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00)
- experimental third-party oAuth-based client authorization option

Comment: btw, for convenience, the code is moved to github: https://github.com/coturn/coturn